# iphone UIImage array memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I had that question before, tried as answered, but still it does not work.

Before I allocated with:

```
imageArray_danceright =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
```

I came adviced to do like bellow, but now it crash immediatly after second anim is called:

---

```
//init areas:

imageArray_stand = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FrankieSingtRetime_0001" ofType:@"jpg"]],
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FrankieSingtRetime_0002" ofType:@"jpg"]],
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FrankiePeaceRetime_0003" ofType:@"jpg"]],nil];


imageArray_danceleft = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]   pathForResource:@"FrankiePeaceRetime_0001" ofType:@"jpg"]],
.. 40 images
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FrankiePeaceRetime_0040" ofType:@"jpg"]],nil];

imageArray_danceright = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FrankiePeaceRetime_0041" ofType:@"jpg"]],
.. 40 images
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FrankiePeaceRetime_0080" ofType:@"jpg"]],nil];


//start:
[myimageview setAnimationImages:imageArray_stand];


myimageview.animationDuration = 0.23;
myimageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
myimageview.animationRepeatCount = 0.0;
myimageview.image = [myimageview.animationImages objectAtIndex:1];
[myimageview startAnimating];


// ------ in my 'touchesBegan" i have:

if ([touch view] == overlay_fuesserechts) { 
    [myimageview.animationImages release];
    [myimageview setAnimationImages:imageArray_danceright];

    myimageview.animationDuration = 2.0;
    myimageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
    myimageview.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [myimageview startAnimating];
}


- (void)dealloc {
[imageArray_stand release];
imageArray_stand=nil;
[imageArray_danceright release];
imageArray_danceright=nil;
[imageArray_danceleft release];
imageArray_danceleft=nil;       
    super dealloc];
 }
```

---

Its starts with the "stand" animation.. but when i fire touchesbegan it crashes immediatly at:

```
    [myimageview setAnimationImages:imageArray_danceright];
```

and i have no idea. I tried so many things. Now I hope you have an idea.

thx
chris

Comment: no .. thats the prob.. it just stop. I made a NSLog before and after the  [myimageview setAnimationImages:imageArray_danceright]; for that reason i know it crash there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are autoreleasing your image arrays, by the time it gets to TouchesBegan they have already been released.
Who told you to use `arrayWithObjects` instead of `alloc` - `initWithObjects` ?
It sounds like your earlier version would have been more correct. What was the problem you were having with that?

Comment: Before it worked just fine... the problem was it does not released the Memory and so after the 4th anim (i could see in Instruments/Allocation) it got 100MB and crashed.  I would even post my old code again if you are willed to help :)

Comment: `[myimageview.animationImages release];` looks wrong to me too. I would make that `myimageview.animationImages = nil;`

Comment: in fact that should be redundant at that point - setAnimationImages should release what it already was holding. Might be worth doing it in dealloc, tho. Does this object own myimageview, too? I don't see you releasing that

Comment: Thanks... I posted my old Code here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448911/iphone-uiimage-array-memory-leak-old
 For this question here... what do you mean with "does this object own myimageview,too" Which Object. Above is all i release.. you may let me know what else to release :) And as mentioned the old code is at the link above. thanks again. btw. should I am able to contact you directly..i would even send you the whole code... should i not find a solution i have to test with a timer and without Animation :(

Answer (score 0):

You surely don't need the `[myimageview.animationImages release];` at the beginning of touches began. You are creating autoreleased array objects and assigening them to the imageview which releases them.

Comment: ok.. i removed the [myimageview.animationImages release]; but still it just crash when     [myimageview setAnimationImages:imageArray_danceright];
is fired ??